# Checking Internet Status using PHP

Tags: php

I would like to check the internet connection status using php. I tried this:

```
<?php


    $connected = @fsockopen("www.google.com"); 
    if ($connected){
        $is_conn = true; //0
        fclose($connected);
    }else{
        $is_conn = false; //1
    }
    echo (int)$is_conn;



?>
```

but it always returns true if I'm connected to the internal notwork! I need it to return false if I'm not online even if I'm connected to internal network.

Comment: What do you mean with internal network? Is there maybe a routing to the internet where you can access google? And you are running this on a local machine? And why are you disable error display with the @?

Comment: No actually I cannot access google! I'm not sure why it returns true. and about disabling error I  was testing something else sorry I forgot to remove it.

Comment: What contains $errmsg when you change fsockopen() to fsockopen("www.google.com",80,$errnbr,$errmsg);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine in php script if connected to internet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860365/determine-in-php-script-if-connected-to-internet)

Answer (score 4):

Make use of this simple code to check whether internet is connected or not.

```
<?php
checkdnsrr('php.net') ? print 1: print 0; // " prints" 1 (If internet is ON)
```

Comment: I think this is slower solution.

Answer (score 2):

when you use [@fsockopen](https://www.php.net/fsockopen) as offline

```
    if (!$sock = @fsockopen('www.google.com',80,$errorNum,$errorMessage)) {

    echo "no connection";
    echo $errorMessage;
}else{
    echo "connection";
    echo $errorMessage;
```

and print error message
will be :

```
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: System error
```